# Checkbox to be checked when condition satisfies

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

How to check the checkbox when condition satisfies?

```
<input name="pt_id[]" id="pt_id" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST["pt_id"])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>&nbsp;<?php echo the_title(); ?>
```

Please help me. Give me solution or suggestion for this?

Comment: It's already in your code. What is not working, what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you want something interactive? If thats the case, then you are probably looking for clientside code (i.e. javascript) as opposed to serverside code.

Comment: After page loading, checkboxes are unchecked. Checkbox values are saved in database correctly.

Comment: The checkbox will only be checked if you do a postback to the page (when $_POST gets populated). If you want the checkbox to be checked if it has been previously checked and saved to the database, then you will want to change your `if(isset($_POST["pt_id"]))` to check the database value.

Comment: I checked with my database values. if(isset($_POST["ck_id"])==$group_posts['ck_id']), but no results

Comment: Why not just `if($group_posts['ck_id'])`? Why are checking the bool value of isset against this?

Answer (score 0):

Well your code already does what you need but using PHP. If you want to catch an event lets say user clicks on a div and you want to check the checkbox then you need to use **javascript/jquery**.

sample code would be (using jquery):

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourdiv', function() {
   $('#pt_id').attr('checked', true);
});
```

this will check the checkbox when **yourdiv** is clicked

if you wish to uncheck it when **div2** is clicked do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#div2', function() {
  $('#pt_id').attr('checked', false);
});
```